# Magento How to display upsell products under cart page

Tags: magento, cart

i am trying to display upsell products under cart page but i am not able to find how we can do this. i can call upsell file under cart page. but products not coming.. code inside file is :

```html
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-up-sell">
    <div class="box-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('You may also be interested in the following product(s)') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="products-grid" id="upsell-product-list">
    <?php // $this->setColumnCount(5); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>
        <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>
            <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(135) ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link) ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('upsell-product-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

if any one has any idea please msg. me.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will by default display cross-sell products on the cart page. You will see it if you inspect `checkout.xml` file.

```
<block type="checkout/cart_crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" as="crosssell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
```

If you want to show upsell on cart page you need to create a custom block which will extend from `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell` class. In your custom block update the `_getCollection` method to use up-sell instead of cross-sell products like this:

```
 protected function _getCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link')->useUpSellLinks()
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->setPageSize($this->_maxItemCount);
        $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection);

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
```

And finally add your up-sell block via layout update. You can keep the same template file as cross-sell block.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="module_namespace/upsell" name="checkout.cart.upsell" as="upsell" template="checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but i am using cross sell products under product page. i don't want to overwrite cross sell section.. i want upset seprate

Comment: even if we are extending cross sell then if we are using crossell somewhere else is this effect current cross sell display

Comment: No it won't affect current display at all. That's one of the main reasons for class inheritance in OOP. You can create a class (in this case Yournamespace_Yourmodule_Block_Cart_Upsell) which extends an existing class (in this case `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Crosssell`) and customise your new one as much as you like without doing anything at all to the pre-existing one.

Comment: "If you want to show upsell on cart page you need to create a custom block" where do I create this custom block?